# Using app scripts to prevent the deletion of a row in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a requirement to prevent the deletion of a row on a sheet if the value of the first cell is found in the first cell of any row in another sheet. 
Is there a way to accomplish this using google app scripts?

Comment: Protect your sheets and let no one modify them. There's no other way to prevent modifications, or to override UI elements / commands to require authentication for them. If you want that type of control, you will need to build a 3rd party client that wraps Google Sheets, and force your users to use the client application. In that client app you would have to explicitly write method handlers for the interaction with google sheets, and thus could prevent users from deleting rows when data is found in certain situations.

Comment: If your schema allows it, you can dedicate one column in the row to displaying the "use count" of that row's value on the other sheets, and apply conditional formatting to the cell / row based on its value, such that your user training / onboarding methods strongly coach them to not use the delete row functionality for rows that have that format / criterion. This will still be an unenforceable recommendation, though - users can simply ignore the value of the column and delete the row anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [onchange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) event to catch the row deletion opreation, then do your checking, I am not sure if you can prevent the deletion but you can **re-insert** the deleted row since the event offers all the information you need to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. A reinsert using cell values from the deleted row would work well for me. I do not see how I can access information about the deleted row. According to the google script docs the properties exposed by the Change event are authmode, changeType, triggerUid and user. Can you offer a suggestion about how I would get hold of the deleted row information?

Comment: you are correct, it is not available in the onchange() event. The only way i can see now is to keep a second copy of the sheet by duplicating inserts and updates using onedit events, then use the getactiverange() during onchange events to compare the result with the mirrored sheet and act accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. At this time I believe there is no reasonable way to perform this parent/child integrity check using app scripts. I am quickly coming to the conclusion that app scripts are not the appropriate tool for what we are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Make a separate column and protect its range like so:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var range = ss.getRange('A1:A');
var protection = range.protect();
```

This will block the rows from deletion for anyone but you, given you are the documents owner.